# Fail to change size of test ad

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm currently trying to add Ads to my app. To do so I've chosen to go with [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner), since it's already implemented in Firebase.

To test it, I used the dedicated test ad unit ID for iOS banners by AdMob: `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716`.

The ad is being displayed but I'm failing to change its size - the test add being displayed as a 320x100 ad and won't fill the width of an IPhone X - ugly black dotted bars are being displayed instead.

**How can I change its size?** Is it even possible to change test ads' sizes?

What I've tried:

```
@IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addAddsToBannerView()
    }

func addAddsToBannerView() {
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        bannerView.delegate = self
}

extension HomeViewController: GADBannerViewDelegate {

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            bannerView.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: show constraints of `bannerView`

Comment: It's added via storyboard, it's both sides 0, and to safe area again zero. I got it working now with Fluid Banners, but when smaller image ads are being loaded, there are still ugly bars - is there away to change their color or similar?